# VSCode Javascript - ES6 Class Instance Generics JSDOC

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, ecmascript-6, jsdoc, es6-class

I've recently found out that you can implement JSDoc generics within VSCode for a javascript project, which is fantastic. A big issue I've had with writing JS in the past is having the intellisense never really knowing which types I'm dealing with.

I followed this documentation on how to implement generics (using the @template annotation): https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#template

It works *mostly* as in I can properly see my class type. The problem is that it doesn't actually seem to know about any of the non-static methods and properties.

Here's some example code:

```
"use strict";

class Parent {
    age = 10;

    outputAge() {
        console.log(`My age is ${this.age}`);
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    name = "Bob";

    outputName() {
        console.log(`My name is ${this.name}`);
    }
}

/**
 * @template T
 * @param {T} classType
 * @returns {T}
 */
function genericFunction(classType) {
    return new classType();
}

const testGeneric = genericFunction(Child);
testGeneric.outputName();
testGeneric.outputAge();
```

The code executes properly. `testGeneric` correctly has the `outputAge()` and `outputName()` methods at runtime.

The problem is that VSCode doesn't seem to know about:

- `age`
- `name`
- `outputAge()`
- `outputName()`

[image: Screenshot of it not showing the fields]

I suspect this is because the way the generics work. It's seemingly knowing it's a type `Child`, but not that it's an instance of `Child`. If I added any static methods, they'd correctly show up in the intellisense.

If I inline annotate `testGeneric` to have a type of `Child`, I can see all the properties and methods:

[image: Screenshot of it working]

My question to you all: Is there a way to correctly setup my template to know it returns an instance of `T` or is this just a limitation/bug in VSCode's intellisense?

Let me know if anything needs clarification.

Comment: Well... the problem is `T` is the constructor... And you're returning the constructor (at least your JSDoc is saying that)...

Comment: Right, that's what I suspected (I state that at the end of my question).

So am I missing syntax to correctly tell VSCode that it's an instance of the class or is this not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I couldn't find anything equivalent to `ReturnType` for JSDoc, I've decided to do the other way, and make the parameter return `T`, so that `@returns {T}` now returns the instance type:

```
/**
 * @template T
 * @param {{ new(...args: any[]): T }} classType
 * @returns {T}
 */
function genericFunction(classType) {
    return new classType();
}
```

Tested with https://vscode.dev/ and [typescriptlang.org/play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=true&declaration=false&target=99&jsx=0&filetype=js#code/EQVwzgpgBGAuBOBLAxrYBuAsAKB8gNgIZhhQAKh8EAdrFAN45TNSEDm0AvFAIwAMWXNhZQA9iFgAHCQEEOACgCUDJiJbJR1MKPwQAdPlFt5AAwCyAT1YcoiUgBJ6sABZ297CAF8TiwSM84AUIExKQAwq74ACZQEAAesDRRpBRUtCrCLNSEALZcUMAAQqIARhg4qsziUhIAcrkQShlq6praugZGppZQ2Xm2Dk6uYHp9Xj5+LEFBOAD0AFTzTPNQAAKJOZJEiVAAKstrkpS5DPS9EADu8no3lGxgAFys1BYA2gC6ik+7UJ6eUCESLsLJIIAdVlRYCB4FoGLsglB5rMcAAzEDUVCITRQDjUCBIZAAMXRmM08kBYGBoOUjEyzEh0Oo5wuAKIQJBjV8gQq2A0WjoiTgAHEaPiUFBuLixUSSbAsdR5BFENEudhBbARXiCXpqtJYPU8kpBOrNdKdRI9XJOeggA)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use @template, then it seems to me that it would be more correct

```
/**
* @template ParentType
* @property {number} age
* @property {function(): void} outputAge
*/
class Parent {
    age = 10;

    outputAge() {
        console.log(`My age is ${this.age}`);
    }
}

/**
* @template ChildType
* @extends {Parent}
* @property {string} name
* @property {function(): void} outputName
*/
class Child extends Parent {
    name = "Bob";

    outputName() {
        console.log(`My name is ${this.name}`);
    }
}

/**
* @template {ChildType} T
* @param {T} classType
* @returns {T}
*/
function genericFunction(classType) {
    return new classType();
}

const testGeneric = genericFunction(Child);
testGeneric.outputName();
testGeneric.outputAge();
```

Comment: That only works for 1 specific class type, which defeats the purpose of using generics, in my opinion.

See the answer I marked here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73830111/12713125

Comment: No, `Parent` and `Child` should not be templated, they're not generic. The question was only about correctly typing the `genericFunction`